# How to move array values to a new column, based on duplicate values in a different column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I'm using python with numpy and pandas and I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
index   title Time  Y
0       Part1 0.5 -117
1       Part1 1.0 -118
2       Part1 1.5 -137
3       Part1 2.0 -123
4       Part2 0.5 -97
5       Part2 1.0 -94
6       Part2 1.5 -95
7       Part2 2.0 -99
```

and I want it to change so that I have the 'part 1' and 'part 2' values according to time.... Like this.

```
index   title Time Part1 Part2
0       Part1 0.5 -117   -97
1       Part1 1.0 -118   -94
2       Part1 1.5 -137   -95
3       Part1 2.0 -123   -99
```

I dont actually need the index or Title column. I just need Time, Part 1 and Part 2.

I've tried making two smaller data frames using the code below and concatenating them but I've ended up with this:

```
a = df.loc[df['title'].str.contains('Part 1')]

b = df.loc[df['title'].str.contains('Part 2')]

c=pd.concat([a,b], axis=1)



index   title Time  Y   title  Time  Y
0       Part1 0.5 -117  nan    nan   nan
1       Part1 1.0 -118  nan    nan   nan
2       Part1 1.5 -137  nan    nan   nan
3       Part1 2.0 -123  nan    nan   nan
4       nan   nan nan   Part2  0.5   -97
5       nan   nan nan   Part2  1.0   -94
6       nan   nan nan   Part2  1.5   -95
7       nan   nan nan   Part2  2.0   -99
```

Does anyone know how to get this into the format so that the Y values are displayed according to the matching values in the 'time' column? I think I could do this with some sort of loop, but was hoping there was a simpler way using a match or built-in function of some sort...

Any help appreciated!

UPDATE!

```
a = a.drop(columns=['title'])
b = b.drop(columns=['title'])
c=pd.merge(a, b, on=['Time'])
```

This makes a new table with 'Time, Y_x, Y_y' as headings. Not perfect as the 'Part number' isn't retained but does the job for me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the `pivot` method:

```
df.pivot(index="time", columns=["title"]).reset_index()
```

You can find more about it in the [pandas official docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html).